# Did Amadeo Bordiga tell off Stalin this way?

Tags: communism, italy, quotes, stalin

I read somewhere that [Amadeo Bordiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeo_Bordiga), Italian Communist, said something along these lines to Stalin's face:

> If the Soviet Union is the homeland of all proletarians and the revolution, then let it be governed by a joint committee of international communist parties!

This is from memory and I'm sure the wording is wrong. I thought I read the quote a few years back in this text by Loren Goldner - "[Communism is the Material Human Community](https://libcom.org/library/communism-is-the-material-human-community-amadeo-bordiga-today)", however, all I find is this:

> Bordiga was the last Western revolutionary who told off Stalin to his face (in 1926) as the gravedigger of the revolution and lived to tell the tale. He was ousted from the PCI in the same year and took several thousand "Bordigists" with him.

[German wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadeo_Bordiga), Bordiga also only mentions that he called Stalin a traitor to the revolution (in 1925).

It is of course possible that the quote I remember was in an earlier version of the text and was removed because it was wrong/inaccurate. The quote is kinda awesome though and I want to know if he really said it, and in what context.

Comment: In 1925-26 it was still possible (and normal) to tell Stalin anything, even some Russians did.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Bordiga may indeed have expressed that sentiment at the Sixth Enlarged Executive Committee Plenum of the Comintern in Moscow in 1926.

In Loren Goldner's paper, [Amadeo Bordiga, the Agrarian Question and the International Revolutionary Movement](https://cominsitu.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/goldner19951.pdf), published in Critique: Journal of Socialist Theory, 1995 (which may be the paper that you were thinking of) she says:

> In his final confrontation with Stalin in Moscow in 1926, **Bordiga proposed that all the Communist Parties of the world should jointly rule the Soviet Union, as a demonstration of the supra-national reality of the workers’ movement**. This proposal was, needless to say, coolly received by Stalin and his friends.

A footnote notes that:

> This intervention was made at the Sixth Enlarged Executive Committee Plenum of the Comintern in 1926.

Comment: There exists a transcript of this plenum at least in Russian. https://books.google.ru/books/about/Шестой_расширенный_пл.html?id=PNyUxAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y Sadly I can't get access to that book now and surely won't be able to pinpoint the exact place. But it would be very nice to find it and also see the reaction. Sometimes the context changes everything...